# Jasper/iReport internationalization with code from datasource

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

My question is quite simple. In a jasper report, the internationalization code for a field comes from the datasource.

ex: `$F{field1}` - contains my code.

I want to write something like `$R{$F{field1}}` but I get errors and it doesn't even compile.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: have u gone through this site http://helicaltech.com/blogs/internationalization-of-jasper-reports-hello-world-example/

what is the error your getting?

Comment: got it to work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

Use: str($F{field1}).